# Laravel Saptie-permission roles get deleted on users that has relation in other table

Tags: php, laravel

My users table has a relation to table instantions that has rule onDelete **restrict**. to prevent deletion on users. But when I try to delete the user it is worked the user not deleted, but the roles get revoked/ deleted.

here is some code

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->delete()
```

How to prevent role get revoked/ deleted when user has relation to other table ?

I'm using spatie role-permission.

Comment: why don't you use transaction !?

Comment: can you give me a hint to use a transaction?

Comment: you can read in here : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database#database-transactions

Comment: you can use it together with `try ... catch`